# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy DataUri Versioning

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We've implemented a set of custom policies, primarily in order to enable JourneyFraming. In order to have the policy follow the existing User Flows, we followed the excellent set of blog posts at [Wojtek wrote](https://blog.wojtek.pro/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-how-to-begin/). Everything is working properly, however, I have some questions specifically regarding how the `DataUri` elements for `ContentDefinition` are built:

1. In my Base XML file, I have `ContentDefinition` items which use a `DataUri` that is of a different version than in my Relying Party XML file. For example, in Base, I have:

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.localaccountlookup2.1">
 <LoadUri>[Custom Blob URI]</LoadUri>
 <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7</DataUri>
 <Metadata>
  <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account lookup page for password reset</Item>
 </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Whereas in RP I have:

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.localaccountlookup2.1">
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.24</DataUri>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Does my overall custom policy implement the highest version declared in the different component files? Or does it always implement the one in my RP file?

2. I also noticed that in my RP file specifically, I reference the same `DataUri` in different `ContentDefinition` elements, however, the version of the `DataUri` differs. For example, I have the following two `ContentDefinition` entries:

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup2.1">
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.24</DataUri>
</ContentDefinition>
<ContentDefinition Id="api.changePhoneNumberVerifyEmailAddress">
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.23</DataUri>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Will this cause a problem, especially if both of these `ContentDefinition` entries are used in the same `UserJourney`?

3. Should we be keeping track of updates to `DataUri` versions, in order to update our policy files to match any changes Microsoft makes? Is there some form of email list or website we can follow in order to track these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it uses inheritance, so as you go "down the chain", any changes overwrite those above i.e. the RP being last will overwrite anything above.

But if you have two api.xxx that reference different versions, each will apply to the technical policy that uses them.

Comment: Hey @rbrayb - thanks for that answer. So, that covers the first question, and somewhat covers the second. But in the second scenario, I'm still unclear as to whether it's a problem if they have different versions. Given we obtained the code by exporting from the default User Flow, I'd guess the answer is no - just that it feels weird to have it use different versions like that. Do you know the answer to the third question?

Comment: No - not a problem

Comment: I only update the DataUri if a feature requires it. No - you have to check the page manually - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout